# Javascript Add Empty Line in to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a poem mobile app. I want to add an empty line to the string after each pair of four lines. `poemValue` input is like this.

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
jjj
kkk
lll
mmm
```

I'm trying to convert the above string to this with string functions:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

eee
fff
ggg
hhh

jjj
kkk
lll
mmm
```

Here's what I've tried so far. Add an empty line when the string line height becomes `5` or divisible to `5` but not working.

```
if (poemValue.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length % 5) {
  value = poemValue + poemValue.concat("\n\n")
} else {
  value = poemValue
}
```

Comment: Is `poemValue` an array or string?

Comment: @ThePyGuy It's a string, seeing as they're calling `split` on it

Comment: poemValue is a string variable

Comment: @Spectric I can see the code but needed confirmation

Comment: @ThePyGuy arrays don't have a `split` method, so clearly it's a string.

Comment: @Spectric It's not necessary that everyone adding the question will know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think testing the number of lines in the input is needed at all - you don't want to conditionally add newlines to the string, you want to *always* add newlines. Match 4 full lines, then replace with those 4 lines plus an empty line.

```js
const input = `aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
jjj
kkk
lll
mmm`;
const output = input.replace(
  /(?:.*\r?\n){4}/gm,
  '$&\n'
);
console.log(output);
```

If you want the number of lines to come from a variable, then interpolate into a `new RegExp`.

```js
const lines = 4;
const input = `aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
jjj
kkk
lll
mmm`;
const output = input.replace(
  new RegExp(`(?:.*\\r?\\n){${lines}}`, 'gm'),
  '$&\n'
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: how can i use variable instead number 4 in regex?